# What is the default default value of a dependency property?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

A WPF dependency property can be given a default value by passing a `PropertyMetadata` with the default value to the `Register` function:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(double), typeof(MyControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
```

What is the default value for the dependency property if no default value is specified, either by not passing a `PropertyMetadata` or by using a `PropertyMetadata` constructor which doesn't specify a default value?

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752375(v=vs.110).aspx) says

> (For cases where a property registration does not specify metadata, a default PropertyMetadata is created with default values for that class.)

but I haven't found anywhere that describes what these default values are.

Comment: `a default PropertyMetadata is created with default values for that class` kinda answers the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference code below is what is called by the `DependencyProperty` when no default value was given by the `PropertyMetadata`.

It uses the standard [default values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/83fhsxwc.aspx) in most cases (`null` for reference types, zeroed for value types), but for enums it uses the first enumerator instead of the enumerator with the value 0 (if they are different).

[referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Workflow.ComponentModel/AuthoringOM/DependencyProperty.cs.html#https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Workflow.ComponentModel/AuthoringOM/DependencyProperty.cs.html,https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Workflow.ComponentModel/AuthoringOM/DependencyProperty.cs.html,https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Workflow.ComponentModel/AuthoringOM/DependencyProperty.cs.html,c14e343a3651b70f)

```
private static object GetDefaultValue(string name, System.Type propertyType, System.Type ownerType)
{
     if (name == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
      if (name.Length == 0)
          throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.Error_EmptyArgument), "name");
      if (propertyType == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyType");
      if (ownerType == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("ownerType");

     object defaultValue = null;
     if (propertyType.IsValueType)
     {
         try
         {
             if (propertyType.IsEnum)
             {
                 Array values = Enum.GetValues(propertyType);
                 if (values.Length > 0)
                     defaultValue = values.GetValue(0);
                 else
                     defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType);
             }
             else
                 defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType);
         }
         catch
         {
         }
     }
     return defaultValue;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the default value for the dependency property if no default value is specified, either by not passing a PropertyMetadata or by using a PropertyMetadata constructor which doesn't specify a default value?

The default value is the default value of the type of the dependency property, i.e. for a `double` dependency property it is `0.0` (or `default(double)`).

You can easily confirm this yourself by creating an instance of your class and access the getter of CLR wrapper of the dependency property:

```
MyControl ctrl = new MyControl();
var x = ctrl.MyProperty; // = 0
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: The default values for all primitive types are documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/83fhsxwc.aspx. A property is just a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a private backing field. And a dependency property and WPF provides a set of services on top of that. But the backing fields still gets the default value of the type. What else could it possibly be set to and how?

Comment: WPF is complicated enough that it wouldn't surprise me if there was something else involved. And according to the code quoted by Dr. Fre in his answer, it does actually do something different, at least for enums.

Comment: Of course a dependency property is different from a CLR property but the default value is the same unless you change it when you register the dependency property. It doesn't get any magic or unexpected default value.

Comment: Again, according to the WPF code quoted quoted by Dr. Fre in his answer, it does actually do something different, at least for enums - it uses the first enumerator rather than the enumerator with the value 0.

Comment: Well, I haven't checked, but this should be considered as an undocumented implementation detail that may be changed in future versions. You should not rely on or depend on it in any way. If you want to assign a dependency property a default value, you should do so when you register the property.

Comment: I agree - that was rather the point, that I couldn't find any documentation.